# What kind of architecture is needed to allow multiple web apps working together that can be updated individually?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm not sure the best way to explain this in words, so I'll give an example to explain what I mean.

When you go to Google, you have a header that contains many different web apps (search, images, gmail etc). These are each independent apps that can be updated separately from all the others, yet share common components (login, the header bar itself etc). How are they doing this?

Right now I have a single app. The top bar has a few different tabs. I need to add two new web apps that can each be updated / sold individually from the other. If someone buys all 3, they should see all 3 in the nav bar. If they only bought 1, they should only see 1. There should be a single login for all these things. I'm not sure how to do this while keeping each thing independent so that can be updated on their own schedule.

The issue is how do I maintain the same nav bar between all 3 sites? This nav bar needs to be configurable (showing only the products they own, as well as other modifications such as font, language etc). I can handle the SSO parts, its the shared code between different apps, and the customization behind it.

Comment: Are you looking for Single-Sign On? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to separate the following concerns:

- login / user data (who is it?)
- licensing (what did they pay for?)
- app metadata (what apps do we sell? their name, icon, URL etc.)
- app framework (the meta nav bar)
- individual apps

To illustrate:

1. You require a sign-on mechanism (custom solution or third party, like OpenID). The login form is the same for all apps and is concerned with user data only. Login queries your customer database to see if we recognize the user who's signing on, and if we do, set a cookie etc. - that's it.
2. Each of your apps must include your "app framework" (think of it as a library), which does the following: For the current user (valid cookie etc.) it queries the licensing database for the apps this user purchased. It can then query your app metadata for the purchased apps and generate a nice nav bar with links/icons of those apps only.
3. Your individual apps do not know anything about the other apps. They don't include any code that deals with logon or switching between apps. All those tasks are delegated to your meta framework, which checks if the user is signed on and generates the nav bar. The app simply displays it at the appropriate place (e.g. top of page).

All of this happens server-sided, of course, and details depend on the actual technologies used.

Answer (score -1):

If you have 3 independent WebApps and want to use a single login for all of them: You might want to look at SSO [Single Sign On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)